# While loop produces wrong dates

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I have the following loop, but it doesn't stop and produces the wrong dates.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
thedate="2018-03-28"
enddate="2018-04-02"
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    thedate=$( date -d "$thedate + $i days" +%F )

    new_date=$( date -d "$thedate " +%Y%m%d )
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$new_date"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

I expected this output:

```
The date is "20180328"
The date is "20180329"
The date is "20180330"
The date is "20180331"
The date is "20180401"
The date is "20180402"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add `set -x` just before the start of the `while` loop, and verify that your script is doing what you really _think_ it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the counter `i` at all.
You just need to increment the current date by 1 in every iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash
thedate="2018-03-28"
enddate="2018-04-02"
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    thedate=$( date -d "$thedate + 1 days" +%F )

    new_date=$( date -d "$thedate " +%Y%m%d )
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$new_date"
done
```